# Symfony and PhpUnit memory leak

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit

We have issues with memory leak when loading Doctrine in our phpunit tests

Starting for Symfony's documentation :
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html we have written this test :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class memoryleakTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $em;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->em->close();
    }

    function testEEE1()  { 
    }
    function testEEE2()  { 
    }
    function testEEE3()  { 
    }
    function testEEE4()  { 
    }
    function testEEE5()  { 
    }
    function testEEE6()  { 
    }
    function testEEE7()  { 
    }
    function testEEE8()  { 
    }
    function testEEE9()  { 
    }
    function testEEE10()  { 
    }
    function testEEE11()  { 
    }
    function testEEE12()  { 
    }
    function testEEE13()  { 
    }
    function testEEE14()  { 
    }
    function testEEE15()  { 
    }
    function testEEE16()  { 
    }
}
```

we got this result (php_memory_usage between parenthesis) :

```
testEEE1: . (42M)
testEEE2: . (42.7M)
testEEE3: . (43.3M)
testEEE4: . (44M)
testEEE5: . (44.8M)
testEEE6: . (45.5M)
testEEE7: . (46.1M)
testEEE8: . (46.8M)
testEEE9: . (47.4M)
testEEE10: . (48.1M)
testEEE11: . (48.7M)
testEEE12: . (49.4M)
testEEE13: . (50.1M)
testEEE14: . (50.7M)
testEEE15: . (51.4M)
testEEE16: . (52M)
```

If we remove the doctrine manager loading in setup, we got (32,7M) for each test

Is it a proper way to unload doctrine after each test in the teardown function ?

Comment: looks ok to me. do you have any curl stuff in there anyway? that caused me catastrophic memory leaks

Comment: @DevDonkey nothing more than exactly nothing in the test : no curl, no DB access... just calling doctrine without using it (so perhaps it loads all the metadata). It seems that all this info loaded in memory are not released, even with a kernel->shutdown()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The full solution as been found here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18236

For each service used in the phpunit test, you have to free it by assigning null to the variable if you want the garbage collector to free memory.

```
protected function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();

    $this->em->close();

    $this->em=null;

    gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

Comment: I don't think caling `gc_collect_cycles();` manually is really important. Anyway, nice shot!

Answer (score 9):

To make this even easier for you, you can have a BaseTestCase.php with a teardown function and put this inside:

```
// Remove properties defined during the test
    $refl = new \ReflectionObject($this);
    foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
        if (!$prop->isStatic() && 0 !== strpos($prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName(), 'PHPUnit_')) {
            $prop->setAccessible(true);
            $prop->setValue($this, null);
        }
    }
```

That piece of code will save you from some headaches :)

Comment: This works great, cut my memory footprint on my tests in half. Thanks!

Comment: I had 104.70MB of memory used at the end of my tests before using your code, and after it went down to 59.85MB, thanks!

Comment: Where would I put BaseTestCase.php ?

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts Anywhere close to your tests, this abstract BaseTestCase will extend \PHP_UNIT * test class and use "teardown" -- your other tests will extend this BaseTestCase - make sure to call `parent::teardown` if you are using it for your top-level test.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, as the memory usage still increases after each test, but definitely makes a lot of difference!

Comment: This doesn't handle properties that have a non-null default value. Better:   
`
protected function releaseMemory() {
    $refl = new \ReflectionObject($this);
    $defaults = $refl->getDefaultProperties();
    foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
      if (!$prop->isStatic() && 0 !== strpos($prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName(), 'PHPUnit_')) {
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $prop->setValue($this, $defaults[$prop->getName()] ?? NULL);
      }
    }
  }
`

Comment: @Jonathan how comes the default has the prop name, seems something is missing from your example

Comment: `$prop->setValue($this, $defaults[$prop->getName()] ?? NULL);` does not set the value of the property as the name of the prop. It sets the value of the property to be the entry in the $defaults array that is keyed by the name of the property.

Comment: @Jonathan that doesn't seem to work for me, so if i have something like private Foo $foo, my code fails but yours too. so i thought yours would try to fix the strict types within these.

Comment: That's interesting, but I don't really understand. I suggest opening a new question and pop a link to it here?